# Docker run always Frozen or WSL Ubuntu distro stopped while waiting for Lifecycle server

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Running into this Error after updating to the latest version of Windows in the Insider Preview program. I have noticed that my Hyper-V settings for Hyper-V Management Tools and Hyper-V platform are now on after applying this Windows update. I do not remember if these were both on prior to update.

**Windows**

[image]

**Error** ⚠

```sh
WSL distro stopped while waiting for Lifecycle server.
  >Stdout:

  >Stderr:
2020/08/08 20:51:59 resolving /mnt/host/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/wsl/docker-wsl-cli.iso...
2020/08/08 20:51:59 copying...
Error: mounting wslCLIDest: open /mnt/host/wsl/docker-desktop-data/isocache/c6c2ec214a20124f40a56bbc09f0f7f8fdc9a217881c0ff725af2e476e4b3734.iso: input/output error
2020/08/08 20:51:59 open /mnt/host/wsl/docker-desktop-data/isocache/c6c2ec214a20124f40a56bbc09f0f7f8fdc9a217881c0ff725af2e476e4b3734.iso: input/output error
mounting wslCLIDest
main.doRun
    /go/src/github.com/docker/pinata/linuxkit/pkg/wsl-bootstrap/main.go:224
main.run.func1
    /go/src/github.com/docker/pinata/linuxkit/pkg/wsl-bootstrap/main.go:83
github.com/docker/pinata/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    /go/src/github.com/docker/pinata/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:762
github.com/docker/pinata/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    /go/src/github.com/docker/pinata/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:852
github.com/docker/pinata/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    /go/src/github.com/docker/pinata/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:800
main.main
    /go/src/github.com/docker/pinata/linuxkit/pkg/wsl-bootstrap/main.go:25
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:203
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357
```

**WSL Spec**

```java
usr@win:/mnt/c/$ neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               usr@win
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ----------------
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Windows 10 x86_64
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Kernel: 4.19.104-microsoft-standard
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Uptime: 3 mins
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Packages: 640 (dpkg)
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Shell: bash 5.0.16
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Terminal: /dev/pts/1
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   CPU: Intel i7-6700K (8) @ 4.007GHz
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   GPU: 9542:00:00.0 Microsoft Corporation Device 008e
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   Memory: 497MiB / 7959MiB
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this. Follow these steps and it might fix it for you as well, this the order I tried these in:

1. Delete your Ubuntu on Windows WSL distro and reinstall it from the Microsoft Store.
2. Clean / Purge data using the Docker Desktop app.
3. Reset Docker to factory defaults using the Docker Desktop app.
4. **Disable Hyper-V Management Tools and Hyper-V platform and reboot Windows** <-------- ✔ real fix for my case.
5. Run Docker commands as a super user `sudo su` <-------- you may need to do this if step 4 does not wok for you.

Answer (score 6):

Update memory to 1G fixed the issue for me. Follow below steps:

Open Windows Terminal/CMD/PowerShell and run the commands below:

```
#turn off all wsl instances such as docker-desktop
wsl --shutdown
notepad "$env:USERPROFILE/.wslconfig"
```

Notepad opens and a new file .wslconfig is created.(if this is the first time)

Edit .wslconfig file with notepad and write down these settings:

```
[wsl2]
memory=1GB
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, WSL sometimes did not mount the c:\ drive after windows startup. Therefore Docker also does not start and aborts with error "WSL distro stopped while waiting for Lifecycle server."

I wrote a .bat script which checks for existing "/mnt/c/". If not there it restarts WSL. Only then Docker is started.

I removed Docker from autostart, instead this script is executed on startup.

```
@echo off
set CHECKDIR="/mnt/c/Users"
echo Check if dir %CHECKDIR% exists.
bash -c "cd %CHECKDIR%" && (
    echo Check successful
) || (
    echo Check failed. Restarting WSL
    wsl --shutdown
)
echo Start Docker
start "" "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe"
```

Maybe this is interesting for some here, as long as this bug is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For `Windows` before re-installing and other stuff, just `reset docker to factory defaults`. Works most of the time on windows env after this.

Answer (score 0):

in ubuntu cmd, code . will install vscode server and this will figure out this problem.